# How to prove that $\sum_p\frac{\ln p}{p^s(p^s-1)}$ converges at $\Re\{s\} >1/2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

I am trying to prove that $$\sum_p\frac{\ln p}{p^s(p^s-1)} = \text{const.} \qquad \Re\{s\} > 1/2,$$
where $\{p\}$ is a set of all primes. Mathematica shows that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^s(x^s-1)} = 0, \qquad \Re\{s\} > 0.$$ But how to show that the sum for all primes $$\sum_p\frac{\ln p}{p^s(p^s-1)}$$ is convergent when $\Re\{s\} > 1/2$?

Comment: What is $Re$ of something?

Comment: @Jacaré It is the real part of the complex number $s$. It is fixed as $\Re\{s\}$.

Comment: This post answers your question: [Difficulty with a meromorphic extension.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424727/difficulty-with-a-meromorphic-extension) but there are [many others](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_p%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln%20p%7D%7Bp%5Es(p%5Es-1)%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: @AnneBauval Very useful links. I will try to understand the proof. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Statement), the $n$th prime $p_n$ is asymptotically $n\log n$. Then, with $\sigma =\operatorname{Re}(s)$,
$$
\left| {\frac{{\log p_n }}{{p_n^s (p_n^s  - 1)}}} \right| \sim \frac{1}{{n^{2\sigma } (\log n)^{2\sigma  - 1} }} 
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. The series formed by the terms on the right-hand side converges iff $\sigma>\frac{1}{2}$ by the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) for instance. Hence your original series is indeed (absolutely) convergent iff $\sigma>\frac{1}{2}$ by the the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test). By the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test), it converges uniformly on every compact subset of $\sigma>\frac{1}{2}$. Thus, by [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem#Uniform_limits), your series defines a holomorphic function of $s$ in the half-plane $\sigma>\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Writing $\sigma=\frac12+c$ where $c > 0$, the denominator has $n^{1+2c}$ and the sum of these converges.

Comment: (PNT is an overkill.)